# Google Sign-In for Android no funciona con el Signed APK

Tags: android-studio

Cuando utilizo las credenciales generadas con el certificado SHA1 con el `debug.keystore` todo funciona correctamente en modo debug con el Android Studio, se genera el `google-service.json` y todo funciona perfectamente.

Sin embargo cuando utilizo el certificado SHA1 generado con el `release.keystore` el `Signed APK` generado no me permite realizar el login.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flyer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_flyer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ServerAuthCodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyNoTitleActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>



    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flyer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })



        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para producción debes obtener su archivo de configuración correspondiente:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

pero recuerda que también debes obtener un id relacionado con el SHA-1 del Keystore de producción ya que no funcionaría con el mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder. Te cuento, he creado un archivo de configuración usando SHA-1 del Keystore de producción. Por tanto se ha generado el ID de cliente con ese SHA-1, y aún así no me funciona en producción. Quizá se deba a que el archivo de configuración para producción se genera en otro sitio. Si es así, ¿me puedes pasar el enlace?. Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: Claro ese archivo debe ser el que genera tu sha1 y para obtenerlo es mediante el link de mi repuesta https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating en donde dice "get a configuration file".

Comment: @JaimeGómezMoraleda que tal Jaime que resultados obtuviste?

Comment: Sí, si es con ese archivo json el que he creado con el SHA1 generado con el almacén de claves para release, pero no me funciona. Desde el primer momento lo usé pero no puedo logearme. Sin embargo, como ya te dije si utilizo el json con el SHA1 para debug en modo debug sí me funciona el login.